# minimum of convex function

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

Suppose $\phi:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth, strictly convex function such that $\lim_{|y|\to\infty}\phi(x,y)=\infty$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. And define $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ 
$$F(x)=\min_{y\in\mathbb{R}}\phi(x,y)$$

I am wondering whether $F$ a convex function? I tried but failed to show
$$F(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)\le tF(x_1)+(1-t)F(x_2)$$
If $F$ is not a convex function, is there any counterexamples?

Comment: Yes it is convex, since $\phi$ is convex therefore its restriction to $x$ dimension is also convex, thus the expression of $F$ is convex. The condition $|y| \rightarrow \infty \Rightarrow \phi \rightarrow \infty$ states that $\phi$ is coercive in $y$ and thus the minimum is in a proper domain around origin, thus the domain of $F$ is also convex. From the convexity of domain and expression of $F$ we conclude that $F$ is convex.

Answer (score 1):

By the assumptions, the minimum with respect to $y$ exists and is unique, so  $F:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is well-defined.

Let $x_1,x_2$, $\lambda\in (0,1)$ be given. Then
$$
\begin{split}
F( \lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2) 
& = \inf_{y\in \mathbb R} \phi(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2, y) \\
& = \inf_{y_1,y_2\in \mathbb R} \phi(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2, \lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda)y_2) \\
& \le \inf_{y_1,y_2\in \mathbb R}( \lambda \phi(x_1,y_1) + (1-\lambda)\phi(x_2,y_2))\\
& = \lambda\inf_{y_1\in \mathbb R}  \phi(x_1,y_1) + (1-\lambda)\inf_{y_2\in \mathbb R}\phi(x_2,y_2)\\
& = \lambda F(x_1) + (1-\lambda) F(x_2).
\end{split}
$$